# How can I maintain production databases in a developer team?

Tags: database-management

So we have many clients using our software (with databases) on many different servers. We also have several developers all making changes to these databases daily.

When developers update their code daily, their database needs to be updated with other developers changes.

And when clients update their software, the databases need to be updated.

We are currently using our own solution to this problem, but it seems like an issue many teams would be facing.

Is there a commercial/OS solution to this?

Comment: There are database diff tools. But in general, you shouldn't even allow programmers to change the database schema. As in, at all. Many programmers think of a database as a huge hash array, without realizing that the latter will outlive their own application. Doing schema changes should be the job of a guy who actually understands databases -- the DBA.